# d3.js: build tree-like nested HTML structure. Closure issue

Tags: javascript, recursion, d3.js, tree

I need to build a nested HTML structure out of tree-like data, with keeping track of the path of each node starting from root (array of names of all the nodes that have to be traversed in order to reach a particular node). I've created a recursive function that builds the html well, but keeping track of path doesn't work.

I've tried to accomplish this by populating the array with name of the node on each step, but wrong values are stored. I suspect it might be js closure trap, but not sure. This is the function:

```
// parent - d3 selection, path - array of parent nodes
function buildTreeRecursively(parent, path) {

    // start from empty if it's root and no array passed
    path = path || []; 

    // populate array with this node's namme
    path.push(parent.datum().name);

    if (!parent.datum().children) return;

    parent.append("div")
        .style('padding-left', path.length * 10 + 'px')
        .text(function(d) { 
            // I'm printing the path here so the you can see the error
            return d.name + ": (" +  path.join(" -> ") + ")" 
        })
        .attr("path", function(d) {
            return path.join(" ")
        }) 
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(function(d) { return d.children || [] })
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .call(function(selection) {
            return buildTreeRecursively(selection, path);
        });
}
```

here's jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g6hgkeh9/2/

Comment: Are you looking for this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

Comment: close, but has to be done in html, with tracking the path of each node

Comment: sorry, i didn't get the point "it has to be done in html"...the example i shared to you is in html..

Comment: I mean using HTML tags (<div>, <span>, etc), and not SVG. But this is done already. The challenge here is to track the path to the node